# Eclipse RCP XMLMultiPageEditorPart errors

Tags: rcp

all
When I use `XMLMultiPageEditorPart`, it makes some errors.

```
File file = new File(path);

   IEditorInput  input = new XMLPInput(file);

   try {
    page.openEditor(input, "org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart");
   } catch (PartInitException e) {

    MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "",  path);
   }
```

Errors:

> org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Text
>   editor does not have a document
>   provider  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3075)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3088)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2553)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:237)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:211)

I think `XMLMultiPageEditorPart` should has its own provider? could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the class XMLPInput from? As you are using File, why can't you use the standard FiledEditorInput or FileStoreEditorInput?